# How to set up Kannel without using a 3rd party gateway service

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, kannel, smpp

I'd like to set up Kannel to send SMS messages without going through a 3rd party gateway like Clickatell or Twilio.  In other words, I'd like to connect to the SMPP server for each wireless services (AT&T, Verizon, etc.).

1. How difficult/easy is it to run a Kannel server this way?
2. Each SMSC has to be configured for each mobile network. What is the support like for each network in the US (AT&T, Verizon, T-mobile, Sprint)?
3. Can someone point me to a tutorial/blog for pulling this off (besides the docs)?

Answer (score 3):

Cotopaxi,

Kannel will happily work with all the carriers in the US. Unfortunately a number of them have highlighted that they are not interested in taking on new direct connects. Only when you end up guaranteeing a minimum amount of revenue, and pay a steep setup cost (> $100K) will you be able to get up and running.

I'm not sure if the company you are working for, is indeed interested in paying those sums of money, but be aware that carrier integration requires a lot of money, certification testing and commitments to ongoing improvements, which aggregators (like mBlox/OpenMarket/Twilio/Nexmo take away from you and deal with on your behalf.

Do take those considerations in mind when deciding on the strategy here.

All the best,

Marijn.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good tutorial: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sending-sms-with-smpp-kannel-and-java on setting up Kannel, but to connect to each SMSC is very costly. Using an aggregator like [OpenMarket](http://www.openmarket.com)/Twilio/etc... is a better solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the project wants to own the server and not use a 3rd party service. 

I realize its probably a massive pain in the ass, but I'd like to see if I can get it to work.  Have you ever connected directly to AT&T's SMSC SMPP server (or someone similar)?

Comment: from what I know the cost of connecting to one SMSC (Like AT&T) could cost in the tens of thousands of dollars, using a aggragator is a fraction of that cost and you get most if not all carriers SMSC's.

Comment: That's what I've been hearing, but I'm trying to get an order of magnitude estimate to the higher ups.  They seem to be big on owning the server, despite my arguments to the contrary.