# Need to setup a local portal that sends free SMS

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, kannel, bulksms, way2sms

One of my customer is asking for setting up his own sms gateway, where his employees share sms freely. I suggested him to go with 1 of the bulk SMS API offered by other vendors. But he is willing to setup his own.

So when i went through different open source SMS gateways i found Kannel is best one. But it looks like we need to buy GSM SIM with some SMS package with GSM modem. By this every SMS sent will be chargable.

My questions is, how do way2sms, 160by2 works? I mean do they get charged by there vendor for free SMS sent by users? If no, Then how users are able to send free SMS?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about business or economics, not programming.

Comment: @RobinGreen there are many questions here asking, how to setup and how  they do it etc..

Comment: OK please link me to one, I'll change my close reason to "duplicate question"

Comment: @RobinGreen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206014/how-to-set-up-kannel-without-using-a-3rd-party-gateway-service

Comment: OK, that's a different question. Here you're asking about the cost aspect, not a programming question. This site is only for programming questions. It's not even for hardware or software questions, or configuration questions.

Comment: Google is your friend, sravis - from the Wikipedia page for Way2SMS "Way2SMS.com is an online portal based in Hyderabad, India, offering free and unlimited SMS across India funded by private advertisements" - in other words, it seems that they sell people's data for advertising.  The best bet for your customers, if they really want SMS and not another messaging system like email, would probably be to research tarifs with large numbers of free SMSes.

Answer (score 0):

**Free sms** is impossible with Kannel. Best way to deal with kannel is buying a sms-server service from a service provider. It will be very cheaper than normal connection fees.
USB Modem will give you problems when try to send bulk sms.